# case_when with formula

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with the `iris` dataframe, and I want to create a column, `Result`, with the following conditions:

if `Sepal.Length >=5`  assign `Result=Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width`
else if `Sepal.Length <5 and Sepal.Length >4.3` assign `Result=Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width`. 
else assign `Result=Sepal.Length/Sepal.Width`

I tried `case_when`, but I think it only works if the assigned value is a string.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: “I think [`case_when`] only works if the assigned value is a string.” — What makes you think that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one :

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
   mutate(Result = case_when(
     Sepal.Length >=5 ~ Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width,
     Sepal.Length <5 & Sepal.Length >4.3 ~ Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width,
     TRUE ~ Sepal.Length/Sepal.Width
   ))
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species    Result
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa 17.850000
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa  7.900000
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa  7.900000
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa  7.700000
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa 18.000000
6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa 21.060000
7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa  8.000000
8            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa 17.000000
9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa  7.300000
10           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa  8.000000
```