# R Case_when, with formula and NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I have read [case_when with formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984107/case-when-with-formula), but my case is complicated by NAs.

The data has 3 columns of interest.
EX1 is amounts paid, EX3 is the number of periods over which they were paid. EX2 records whether the periods reported are weekly or monthly.
The drop_na is because I have some data quality issues with a few rows having NAs in those columns  but not in EX2.

I am trying to work out how much the total payments for the year, and store this in a new column, EX. The NA values for EX2 need to become 0 so I can do some further calculations on them.

```
EX1 EX2   EX3
20  week  1
100 week  2
400 month 5
100 month 1
NA  NA    NA
NA  NA    NA
40  week  2

data %>%
  drop_na(EX1, EX3) %>%
  mutate(EX = case_when(EX2 == "week" ~ ((EX1/EX3)*52),
                           EX2 == "month" ~ ((EX/EX3)*(12/52)),
                           TRUE ~ 0))
```

Comment: can you show your expected output. - `drop_na` removes the NA rows

Comment: In the second case, your formula shows `EX/EX3` whereas `EX` was not created at that stage

Comment: Use `is.na(EX2)~ 0`  . Logical on LHS; value on RHS

Comment: I want to get rid of the NAs completely, and the second case should be EX1/EX3

Answer (score 0):

If we are using both case 'EX1', then use `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(EX = replace(replace(rep(NA_real_, n()), EX2 %in% "week",
   ((EX1/EX3)*52)[EX2 %in% "week"]),
    EX2 %in% "month", ((EX1/EX3)*(12/52))[EX2 %in% "month"]))
```

-output

```
  EX1   EX2 EX3         EX
1  20  week   1 1040.00000
2 100  week   2 2600.00000
3 400 month   5   18.46154
4 100 month   1   23.07692
5  NA  <NA>  NA         NA
6  NA  <NA>  NA         NA
7  40  week   2 1040.00000
```